# Magento 2: Newsletter Sending Takes Time

Tags: magento2, cron, newsletter

I'm able to get Newsletter which is set from Newsletter Queue.

If I set immediate date time then also it takes 7 to 10 minutes to sent email to users.

Is there any way that it will send immediate once u start the queue?

Does it belongs to **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> System -> Cron (Scheduled Tasks)** Settings?

Comment: Can you please check the value of 'Generate Schedules Every' in Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> System -> Cron (Scheduled Tasks) ?

Comment: Hi @SHPatel It's default one. I didn't changed that

Answer (score 0):

You can use below extension to analyze cron task with eny error or warning.

https://github.com/shockwavemk/magento2-module-cron-schedule

After installation, you can see whole cron timeline in backend like following image.

[image]

Comment: Kishan extension helps but it would not solve main issue